# What is the word for the period between two Mars conjunctions?

Tags: history, terminology, conjunction

Earth and Mars have conjunctions every 15/7 of a year, or every 26 month or every 2 years. And it varies substantially from conjunction to conjunction because of orbital precessions and eccentricities. Is there an astronomical term for the period between two conjunctions? Like the word "olympiad" which refers to the four year period between the games.

Answer (score 5):

That is called the synodic period.

Comment: How does one phrase it in terms of Earth and Mars? The conjunctions in years 2033, 2035 and 2037 are closer than average. What should I call the synodic period between the conjunctions of 2033 and 2035?

Comment: "The synodic period between the Earth-Mars conjunctions of 2033 and 2035."

Comment: We need to make up a convenient word for that. Something like *"The olympics of 2035".*

Comment: @LocalFluff _A synodical_ [could work](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synodic) as a noun (like e.g. _a sabbatical_ used both as an adjective or a noun).

Comment: @TildalWave The word ["synod"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=synod&allowed_in_frame=0) might work. *"The Martian synod to 2033."* With the risk of being arrested if one talks like that on the street.

Comment: @LocalFluff That could work for the conjunction itself, I thought you were after the word to describe the period leading to it (or between two events), like _olympiad_ (the four-year period between the olympics). Otherwise, why wouldn't you simply use _conjunction_ then?

Comment: @TildalWave I don't know, it is I who am asking the bloody questions here! :) *"The Martian interconjunctional synodic period of 26 months in 2033/2035"* Would any sensible people even try to understand that? Today we say that the month is August, a language so convenient that it is used even by all those who never look up. A unit of time between 2 and 2½ years is becoming important, now, with Mars exploration. I think we should find a catching name for it. Why not simply say *"the synod of '33"*. Or of '35, help me!

Comment: @LocalFluff Oh I don't know, what's the Babylonian word for 15/7? :)

Comment: @TildalWave Maybe: Two. (Hand waving astronomers now and then...)